# How to get Corner Radius in TextInputLayout OutlinedBox style on android

Tags: android, material-design, android-textinputlayout

How to achieve this below design

[image: How to achive this design]

I can able to achieve this below design. How can I add a radius to the box[image]

This is my code

```
    <style name="TextInputLayoutStyle" parent="@style/Widget.MaterialComponents.TextInputLayout.OutlinedBox">
    <item name="boxBackgroundColor">@color/neutralWhite</item>
    <item name="boxStrokeColor">@color/secondaryOrange</item>
    <item name="hintTextColor">@color/secondaryOrange</item>
    <item name="android:textColorHint">@color/neutralDark</item>
    <item name="textColor">@color/neutralDark</item>
    <item name="errorEnabled">true</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusTopStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomStart">10dp</item>
    <item name="boxCornerRadiusBottomEnd">10dp</item>
    <item name="hintTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
    <item name="errorTextAppearance">@style/HintText</item>
</style>
```

and my XML

```
    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout
    android:id="@+id/userId"
    style="@style/TextInputLayoutStyle"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    android:hint="@string/passwordPlaceholder"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toBottomOf="@id/signInHeader">

    <com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputEditText
        style="@style/TextInputEditText"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:inputType="text" />

</com.google.android.material.textfield.TextInputLayout>
```

Comment: There's no way to do that, as is. It just clips a plain rectangle there: https://github.com/material-components/material-components-android/blob/master/lib/java/com/google/android/material/textfield/CutoutDrawable.java#L91.

Comment: @MikeM. Thanks for your information